Could not find a driver for automationName 'UIAutomator2' and platformName 'ANDROID' - Appium Issue

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AppiumBasics {

    @Test
    public void appiumTest() throws MalformedURLException {

        // we need the code to start the server, then it will perform all the operations and stop the server.
        File appiumJS = new File("npm//node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js");

        // Configure and start the Appium service
        AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withAppiumJS(appiumJS)
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .usingPort(4723)
                .build();

        service.start();

        //Define DesiredCapabilities for UIAutomator2
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UIAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:deviceName", "MobileAutomationMachine"); // Or specify your device name
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:app", "D://Appium//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk");   // Path to the app APK file

        // Initialize the Appium driver
        AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
        // Actual Automation

        driver.quit();
        service.stop();
    }
}

Not able to run Appium server through Code given above. when I am starting server manually and hitting the below code runs properly.
Below is the error which I am getting after trying to start the appium server through Automation. I have given the entire error below and deleted some unnecessary portions of it.
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.12.1
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium] { address: '127.0.0.1' }
[Appium] The autodetected Appium home path: C:\Users\ATHAR\.appium
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://127.0.0.1:4723
[Appium] No drivers have been installed in C:\Users\ATHAR\.appium. Use the "appium driver" command to install the one(s) you want to use.
[Appium] No plugins have been installed. Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.
[HTTP] --> GET /status {}
[AppiumDriver@996d] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[AppiumDriver@996d] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"ready":true,"message":"The server is ready to accept new connections","build":{"version":"2.12.1"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 200 5 ms - 111 
[HTTP] Request idempotency key: 715bbf9f-a382-4c11-8da4-dcd6c7152f1d
[HTTP] --> POST /session {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"D://Appium//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk","appium:automationName":"UIAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"MobileAutomationMachine","platformName":"ANDROID"}]}}
[AppiumDriver@996d] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:app":"D://Appium//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk","appium:automationName":"UIAutomator2","appium:deviceName":"MobileAutomationMachine","platformName":"ANDROID"}]}]
[AppiumDriver@996d] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1731433345127 (23:12:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[Appium] Attempting to find matching driver for automationName 'UIAutomator2' and platformName 'ANDROID'
[AppiumDriver@996d] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1731433345131 (23:12:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
**[AppiumDriver@996d] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'UIAutomator2' and platformName 'ANDROID'. Have you installed a driver that supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see.** (Lower-level error: Could not find installed driver to support given caps)
    at DriverConfig.findMatchingDriver 

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'UIAutomator2' and platformName 'ANDROID'. Have you installed a driver that supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see. (Lower-level error: Could not find installed driver to support given caps) 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-LGNE5KF', ip: '192.168.0.105'
Build info: version: '4.26.0', revision: '8ccf0219d7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.10'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {appium:app: D://Appium//resources//ApiD..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: MobileAutomationMachine, platformName: ANDROID}]}]
Capabilities {appium:app: D://Appium//resources//ApiD..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: MobileAutomationMachine, platformName: ANDROID}


Can anybody help with the above issue. I am stuck with this.

Have you installed the uiautomator2 driver? https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/quickstart/uiauto2-driver/

Yes, I have installed on my Laptop.

- uiautomator2@3.8.2 [installed (npm)]
- xcuitest [not installed]
- espresso [not installed]
- mac2 [not installed]
- windows [not installed]
- safari [not installed]
- gecko [not installed]
- chromium [not installed] ```

[Appium] AndroidUiautomator2Driver has been successfully loaded in 1.745s
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLs in your client code to connect to this server:
http://192.168.0.105:4723/
http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - uiautomator2@3.8.2 (automationName 'UiAutomator2')
[Appium] No plugins have been installed. Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.

@kenWolf as you can see I have installed the UIautomator
